# Why is it returning false in the output?

Tags: java

```
public class StringPalindromeCheckUsingRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("ABBBBA"));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        int i = str.length() - 1;
        return stringInterchange(str, "", str, i);
    }

    public static boolean stringInterchange(String original, String toBeModified, String check, int index) {
        if(index >= 0) {
            char character = original.charAt(index);
            toBeModified = toBeModified + character;
            stringInterchange(original, toBeModified, check, index - 1);
        }
        return toBeModified.equals(check);
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging it and it shows that after execution of return statement once all the recursive functions calls are done , function calls again start implementing don't know why ?

Comment: Because you need to - `return yourRecursiveMethodCallHere(parameters);`

Comment: And btw title is poor, please edit to summarize the technical issue.

Comment: btw, *if* you must use recursion (not recommended), consider this pseudo code: `return (length is less than 2) or (first letter equals last letter and same is true with first and last removed)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the `stringInterchange` call.

Also, it would help to name your params appropriately and eliminate unused params.

```java
public class StringPalindromeCheckUsingRecursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("ABBBBA"));  // true
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("RACECAR")); // true
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String source) {
        return stringInterchange(source, "", source.length() - 1);
    }

    private static boolean stringInterchange(String source, String reversed, int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            return source.equals(reversed); // Base case
        }
        return stringInterchange(source, reversed + source.charAt(index), index - 1);
        //   ^-- Make sure you return the recursive call
    }
}
```

For a performance improvement, I recommend using a `StringBuffer` instead of concatenating. If you want even more speed, you can use `StringBuilder`, since this should only be using a single thread.

```java
public class StringPalindromeCheckUsingRecursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("ABBBBA"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("RACECAR"));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String source) {
        return stringInterchange(source, new StringBuffer(source.length()), source.length() - 1);
    }

    public static boolean stringInterchange(String source, StringBuffer reversed, int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            return source.contentEquals(reversed); // Base case
        }
        return stringInterchange(source, reversed.append(source.charAt(index)), index - 1);
    }
}
```